# Sharepoint 2010 on premise and Office 365 web apps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, office-web-apps

Is it possible to integrate sharepoint 2010 on-premise with office web applications provided by office 365? Or I have to install office web apps locally if I want to use them in my farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to install Office Web Apps on your farm.